# Почему выдает ошибку параметра во вьюхе?

Tags: php, laravel

У меня есть страница search.blade.php, на которой множество блоков с картинкой и титулкой, я кликаю по ссылке,чтоб перейти в профайл этого блока, а оно выдает ошибку....
Файл search.blade.php:

```
 @extends('layouts.master')

 @section('content')

 @foreach($properties->chunk(4) as $propertyChunk)
    <div class="row">
        @foreach($propertyChunk as $property)
            <div class="col-md-3">                    
               <img src="{{ $property->imagePath }}" alt="..." class="img-responsive">                     
               <h3>{{ $property->title }}</h3>
               <a href="{{ route('sh.search.propertyprofile') }}">Property Profile</a>
           </div>                
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
@endsection
```

файл propertyprofile.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
   <img src="{{ $properties['imagePath'] }}" alt="..." class="img-responsive">
   <h3>{{ $properties['title'] }}</h3>
@endsection
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
Undefined index: imagePath(View: /var/www/projects/auth.laravel.com/resources/views/sh/propertyprofile.blade.php)
```

Почему он выдает такую ошибку?я же обращаюсь к параметру массива,который создается в модели!Почему он не подтягивает значения в файле propertyprofile.blade.php?

добавляю файл routes/web.php:

```
Route::get('/search', [
  'uses' => 'SearchController@getSearch',
  'as' => 'sh.search'
]);

Route::get('/search/propertyprofile', [
  'uses' => 'PropertyProfileController@getPropertyProfile',
  'as' => 'sh.search.propertyprofile'
]);
```

Файлы SearchController и PropertyProfileController:

```
class SearchController extends Controller
{
public function getSearch() {
    $properties = Property::all();
    return view('sh.search', ['properties' => $properties]);
}    }

class PropertyProfileController extends Controller
{
public function getPropertyProfile() {
    $properties = Property::all();
    return view('sh.propertyprofile', ['properties' => $properties]);
}    }
```

Эти контроллеры одинаковые, массив properties передается так же....только вьюха search подхватывает данные из массива, а вьюха propertyprofile -нет...
П.С.:если НЕ использовать массив properties во вьюхе propertyprofile, а написать Hello world, то на экране будет Hello world.

модель Property :

```
  class Property extends Model
  {
  protected $fillable = ['imagePath', 'title', 'description', 'price', 'id'];
  }
```

Comment: тоже самое : Undefined index: imagePath(...)

Comment: да, перед вызовом  $property->imagePath , таккая же ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы же переходите по ссылке `route('sh.search.propertyprofile')`, проверьте в routes.php или routes/web.php (в зависимости от версии Laravel) или через `php artisan routes:list` куда ведет этот путь.

Вот там куда ведет этот путь вы видимо не передаете на вьюху массив `$properties`, тот код в вопросе к проблеме отношения не имеет.

UPD. Вы выводите на файл `sh.propertyprofile` массив объектов, а не 1 объект, если вы хотите детально выводить информацию по Property, то нужно в `search.blade.php` заменить:

```
<a href="{{ route('sh.search.propertyprofile') }}">Property Profile</a>
```

на

```
<a href="{{ route('sh.search.propertyprofile', ['id' => $property->id]) }}">Property Profile</a>
```

Замените `$property->id` на свою колонку которая у вас отвечает за Primary Key.
И дальше в routes/web.php замените:

```
Route::get('/search/propertyprofile', [
  'uses' => 'PropertyProfileController@getPropertyProfile',
  'as' => 'sh.search.propertyprofile'
]);
```

на

```
Route::get('/search/propertyprofile/{id}', [
  'uses' => 'PropertyProfileController@getPropertyProfile',
  'as' => 'sh.search.propertyprofile'
]);
```

Потом в PropertyProfileController замените:

```
public function getPropertyProfile() {
    $properties = Property::all();
    return view('sh.propertyprofile', ['properties' => $properties]);
}
```

на

```
public function getPropertyProfile($id) {
    $property = Property::first($id);
    return view('sh.propertyprofile', ['property' => $property]);
}
```

И наконец то в файле propertyprofile.blade.php замените:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
   <img src="{{ $properties['imagePath'] }}" alt="..." class="img-responsive">
   <h3>{{ $properties['title'] }}</h3>
@endsection
```

на

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
   <img src="{{ $property->imagePath }}" alt="..." class="img-responsive">
   <h3>{{ $property->title }}</h3>
@endsection
```

И тогда у вас будет работать детальная страница.

Comment: laravel 5.3!  ВСе верно!!!во вторую вьюху он НЕ передает массив!!вот я и не пойму ПОЧЕМУ???я вьюху и контроллер propertyprofile делал по подобию search!

Comment: Расписал как сделать детальную страницу, в данный момент у вас происходят аналогичные действия в этих контроллерах

Comment: Сделал ВСЁ, как Вы написали (отдельное огромное человеческое спасибо за это), в адрессной строке появляется id (у меня это тоже главный ключ), но выдает ошибку :   FatalThrowableError in Grammar.php line 107: Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::columnize() must be of the type array, string given, called in /var/www/projects/auth.laravel.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php on line 123

Comment: Это ошибка из-за вашей БД как я понял, почитайте как выбирать по id с вашей БД в Laravel и замените эту строку $property = Property::first($id); на свою

Comment: Yaroslav Molchan, я добавил код модели Property, чтоб была ясна ситуация полностью!Смотрите, строка $property = Property::first($id);- берет ПЕРВЫМ элемент $id, который соответствует 'id' в database, верно?в моей БД есть ВСЕ параметры, описанные в модели Property. Или я что-то не так понял?